# Update...Delimiter is showing up in my array values caused by Platform or Emulator

Tags: java, android, arrays, split

When I debug the code below it stores the "," (split delimiter) as a value in the array `rawData`. When `parseDouble` gets to that value I get a `NumberFormatException`. Any ideas?

```
package com.simplydesign.android.standarddev;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        final EditText userData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final TextView dataCollection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String[] rawData;
                rawData = userData.getText().toString().split(",");
                dataCollection.setText(calculate(rawData));
            }

        });

    }

    public String calculate(String[] a) {

        double[] convertedData = new double[a.length];
        double sum = 0.0;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int t = 0;

        for (int f = 0; f<a.length;f++){
        convertedData[f] = Double.parseDouble(a[t]);
        t++;

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < convertedData.length; k++) {
            sum += convertedData[k];
        }
        output.append(sum);
        return output.toString();

    }
}
```

After a lot of trial and error I have concluded that my problem was coming from a faulty platform / emulator combination. Originally I had my project platform set to 2.1 with an API value of 7.

For whatever reason this was causing problems when I used a comma as a delimiter. It also gave me problems when my numbers had decimal points (the decimal points looked hollow).

Now I have my project set to 1.6 and it works with the comma and decimal points.

Although I found the solution I still don't understand why this is happening. I feel like some of the apps I create need to be on a high platform, at least 2.5. Is 1.6 ok for most apps? Any suggestions on this matter would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What does your input string look like?

Comment: What is the value of the string?

Comment: It could be anything. It's calling on an EditText box. So the text would be something like "1.3,2.3,4.5,65".

Comment: It could be anything?  That sounds like a recipe for a disaster (or a NumberFormatException).  You'll have to sanitize the String before you can safely call `parseDouble`.

Comment: @user778144: "So the text would be something like "1.3,2.3,4.5,65"" - I find your problem difficult to understand - I use split(...) extensively for CSV files and I've never seen the delimiter appear in the resultant array. Are you saying that if you 'split' that exact string you'll end up with an array of 7 elements? In other words "1.3" "," "2.3" "," "4.5" "," "65" ?

Comment: MisterSquonk -- Yes! That's what shows up in the value field when I debug using eclipse. I usually use Dr. Java to make simple Java problems and never run into this problem.

Comment: OK, this should blow your mind... Just for kicks I changed my delimiter from "," to "/" and it works just fine! Does android have something against a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TextUtils.split](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @atomSmasher Be sure that you dont have a problem with the format of your string... Maybe there's a "," at the end of String thus the last element of array is an empty string and it will get into exception.